# AUTOIT: How to get the current selection in win menu

Tags: autoit

How can you get the current selected item in a menu? For instance is in notepad. How to identify if the current selected is "Font..."

Thanks in advance!

```
ShellExecute("notepad.exe")
WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad")
Send("!O")
Send("{DOWN}")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Iterate through the items in the menu looking for the one that is highlighted. For submenus, the parent item will also be highlighted, so you can recurse through the menu like this:

```
#include <GUIMenu.au3>

ShellExecute("notepad.exe")
WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad")
Send("!O")
Send("{DOWN}")

Sleep(100)

$hMenu = _GUICtrlMenu_GetMenu(WinGetHandle("Untitled - Notepad"))
MsgBox(0, "test", _GetSelected($hMenu))


Func _GetSelected($hMenu)
    Local $iItem = 0, $ret, $sub

    While 1
        Local $tInfo = _GUICtrlMenu_GetItemInfo($hMenu, $iItem, True)
        If @error Or Not @extended Then ExitLoop

        If BitAND(DllStructGetData($tInfo, "State"), $MFS_HILITE) Then
            $sub = DllStructGetData($tInfo, "SubMenu")

            If $sub Then
                $ret = _GetSelected($sub)

                If $ret <> "" Then Return $iItem & "-" & $ret
            EndIf

            Return $iItem
        EndIf

        $iItem += 1
    WEnd

    Return ""
EndFunc   ;==>_GetSelected
```

Comment: Is it possible to read if, for example, the item returned is "Font..." item or not?

Comment: Yes, just look at `_GUICtrlMenu_` functions. Where I have `Return $iItem` just change that to `Return _GUICtrlMenu_GetItemText($hMenu, $iItem)` and change `Return $iItem & "-" & $ret` to `Return $ret`.